# Getting newest ubuntu ISO on a filesize-capped network

Tags: 16.04, downloads, iso, bittorrent

This question might not be best suited on this board, but I'll just give it a shot.

The network at my workplace has a download cap for filesizes and the regular 16.04 download is too big. I can't download a torrent either because obviously the webfilter doesn't allow me to download torrents, but I've managed to download other regular files in the past. So if maybe there's a way to download the newest version in decently sized archives, I could just unzip it locally after downloading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the cap is?

Comment: An alternative is to buy a DVD disk or USB pendrive with Ubuntu. You can buy them via the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### MinimalCD (Network installer)

You can use Ubuntu minimal installer, it's around "50 MB", so you can easily download it and start your installation, the installer will download all necessary parts separately. As you know Ubuntu packages do not come with huge size, they are pretty small, so you can do your installation without any problem and limitation. more information about [MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

---

#### zsync

If you already have an old iso and are running an Ubuntu or other GNU/Linux distribution, you can convert it to your desired version useing `zsync`. it downloads only the parts of a file that are changed. So it's not  going to download a one big file and you will be fine with this method I guess. for more information about `zsync` have a look at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ZsyncCdImage).

---

#### Jigdo

Jigdo is somehow similar to zsync.

> It can be used to efficiently download daily alternate CD builds or update existing alternate .iso images without the need to re-download the entire CD image.

[Jigdo help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DownloadHowto)

---

Alternatively you can remotely upload the Ubuntu ISO on a file server, then `zip` it in multi-parts and download that parts separately.

However if your network file size capacity is really restricted none of them may work for you.